# Access dynamic URL param in angular 6

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

In my `angular 7` code I'm trying to fetch the `clientId` passed in the URL. `clientId` will be dynamic.

```
localhost:4200/client/xyz
```

app.routing.ts

```
 {
  path: 'client/:clientId',
  component: AppComponent
 },
```

app.component.ts

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
   console.log(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('clientId'));
});
```

It prints `null` in the console

Comment: Is it Angular 6 or Angular 7? Question text and title say different.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the route params using this method

```js
this.route.params.subsribe(params => {
  console.log(params['clientId'])
});
```

or

```js
this.activateRoute.snapshot.params['clientId']
```

PLease let me know if you still have problem

Answer (score 0):

Use `params` instead of `paramMap`,

```
console.log(this.route.snapshot.params['clientId']);
```